# Spark Standalone Cluster: TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark

I have a cluster in Amazon EC2 compuse by:
- Master: t2.large
- 2xSlaves: t2.micro

I just change the port in my spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8888
```

And in slave file I wrote my two slaves IPs.

That's all configuration I set up. After that, I run using ./start-all, and I can see my master in 8888 port.

But when I try to run application I get the following WARN:

```
17/02/23 13:57:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 6 tasks
17/02/23 13:57:17 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
17/02/23 13:57:32 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
17/02/23 13:57:47 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

When I check my cluster, I can see how spark kill executor a create a new ones. I tried using better computers and still doesn't work.
What is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you seeing any resources available? Did you set your workers to correctly connect to your master node?

Comment: I didn't setting up anything in my workers, because I could see in my cluster and I thought it was completly ok. What should I set?

Comment: You need to make sure your workers know which master to connect to. You set that up in the `spark-env.sh` file.

Comment: After setting up in slaves, I still have same problem. I used the following sentence in spark-env.sh: export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='172.31.24.154'

Comment: Did you restart the spark worker services?

Comment: I did a stop-all.sh and a start-all.sh from master. I thought maybe something wrong is happening with ports because ec2. I have opend the following ports: 8888, 8080, 22, 7077, 6066, 8081. do i need another one else?

Comment: I already tried opening all ports and didn't work. Can I have any problems because of the private and public ip? I am using all the time private ip in configuration files.